# Make a JavaScript code (injected with selenium) survive page reload

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm working on a macro recording and playback system with `selenium` and JavaScript. At some point I run a JavaScript code that basically subscribes a new even handler to all `window` events, and dumps to the `localStorage` some event data, that I will later collect. The problem is that when the user clicks a link, or by some other reason the page is reloaded, the event handlers are lost. All the data so far is still in the `localStorage`, but I cannot continue collecting new data.

I don't have control of the server, so I cannot insert code in the page source. I can only control the browser using `selenium`, so all I can do is execute some JavaScript at some point to start dumping events, and some JavaScript at a later point to recover the events data. The user might be browsing StackOverflow, for what I know.

Is there any workaround?

PS: I'm using `selenium for python`, if that matters.

Comment: For the time being I'm just periodically (every 1 sec) executing a JavaScript that checks for the existence of a global flag and if it doesn't find it, it reattaches all event handlers. Its not a pretty solution, but it works for me... Still looking for a clean way to solve it, in case someone has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a proxy, such as [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), then you can integrate that with an ICAP* server  to transform the pages before they arrive at your browser. This would allow any page to be altered before it arrives at the browser, inserting your javascript.

Squid version 3 or greater comes with an [integrated ICAP server](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/ICAP#Squid_Configuration).

* Internet Content Adaptation Protocol - defined in [RFC 3507](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3507.txt)

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. My final decision was to implement a custom proxy in Sublime Text, plugin-style, and do more or less what you suggest. I'm using a custom proxy because I'd prefer my plugin to be self-contained. But your suggestion is pretty much the answer, so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a very really good simple solution:

To make the injection easiest you can the the [Gatejs SPDY/HTTP proxy](http://gatejs.org/) and use [the injection gatejs opcode](http://gatejs.org/index.php//documentation/1-8/opcode-forward-injection.html) - it works both on forward and reverse proxy.

Gatejs injection will try to add you html code into a content of type HTML (text/html).

Below a forward proxy example using injection.

```
var serverConfig = function(bs) { return({
    hostname: "testServer0",
    runDir: "/tmp/gatejs",
    dataDir: "/path/to/dataDir",
    logDir: "/var/log/gatejs",

    http: {
        testInterface: {
            type: 'forward',
            port: 8080,
            pipeline: 'pipetest'
        },
    },
    pipeline: {
        pipetest: [
            ['injection', {
                 code: "<h1>w00t injection</h1>"
            }],
            ['proxyPass', { mode: 'host', timeout: 10 }]
        ],
    }
})};
```

mk-